# cannot find the configuration file and content for SSL cert with apache2 and Huawei Cloud

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, apache2, php-8.2, huawei-cloud

Im using Huawei cloud free certificate. I tried follow the instruction from the huawei like the given screen capture below
[image]
i've trying find the configuration file in two types of installation system. with and without docker.

- with docker:
  im using php8.2 and apache2 with Dockerfile:

  ```
  FROM php:8.2-apache
  ```
- without docker:https://cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/how-to-setup-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-20-04/

I've already explore several different folder from inside of two types of the installation. But, i cannot follow the instruction because i cannot find the file and the content as mentioned in the screen capture docs.

Also already trying this tutorial but still cannot moving forward
[https://access.redhat.com/documentation/id-id/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/reference_guide/s1-apache-config#:~:text=The%20Apache%20HTTP%20Server%20configuration,conf%20](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/id-id/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/reference_guide/s1-apache-config#:%7E:text=The%20Apache%20HTTP%20Server%20configuration,conf%20)

please help. Thanks.